# Administrator configuration menu limited. Can't uncheck "Use system value" case

Tags: configuration, paypal, backend, export, system-config

I just updated magento to version 2.1.4 and this type of bug show off right after the update. *(cf. screen)* 
[image: I can't uncheck.]

This error happens on every "Store View" form.

Can you help me ?

Answer (score 1):

Ok I just found the answer !
It was not a problem about Magento 2.1.4, I have to export a configuration that was saved under: "../app/etc/config.local.php". I removed it and all worked normally.